# How can I resolve this error in Matplot++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I downloaded `Matplot++-1.2.0-win64.exe`, and ran the executable.

The files were installed in `C:\Program Files`.

I added the include files and lib files to my project and tried to build the follwoing source code:

```
#include <matplot/matplot.h>

int main() {
    using namespace matplot;

    // Generate some data to plot
    std::vector<double> x = linspace(0, 2 * pi, 100);
    std::vector<double> y = transform(x, [](double xi) { return sin(xi); });

    // Plot the data
    plot(x, y);

    // Display the plot with appropriate labels
    title("Sine Wave");
    xlabel("x");
    ylabel("sin(x)");

    // Save the plot to a file
    save("sine_wave.png");

    // Show the plot in a window
    show();

    return 0;
}
```

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: RouseModelPlot, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>AutocorrelationPlot.cpp
1>computeDiffusionCoeffD.cpp
1>FileIO.cpp
1>LinearPlot.cpp
1>LogLogPlot.cpp
1>main.cpp
1>mainLinearPlotTest.cpp
1>MainLogLogPlotTest.cpp
1>mainMinimalBgiM.cpp
1>mainMSDplotLogLog_1.cpp
1>mainMSDplotLogLog_2.cpp
1>mainR2plotLinear.cpp
1>mainR2plotLogLog.cpp
1>R2.cpp
1>R2.hpp
1>LinearPlot.hpp
1>Vec3.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>x64\Debug\R2.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
1>x64\Debug\LinearPlot.obj : warning LNK4042: object specified more than once; extras ignored
1>matplot.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(figure_type.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(figure_type.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(axes_type.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(axes_type.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(axes_functions.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(axes_functions.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(figure_registry.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(figure_registry.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(colors.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(colors.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(gnuplot.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(gnuplot.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(backend_registry.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(backend_registry.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(axis_type.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(axis_type.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(line.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(line.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(histogram.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(histogram.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(axes_object.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(axes_object.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(line_spec.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(line_spec.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(legend.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(legend.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(error_bar.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(error_bar.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(function_line.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(function_line.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(contourc.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(contourc.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(world_map_10m.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(world_map_10m.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(world_map_50m.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(world_map_50m.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(world_map_110m.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(world_map_110m.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(bars.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(bars.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(box_chart.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(box_chart.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(circles.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(circles.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(contours.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(contours.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(filled_area.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(filled_area.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(labels.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(labels.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(matrix.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(matrix.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(network.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(network.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(parallel_lines.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(parallel_lines.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(stair.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(stair.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(string_function.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(string_function.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(surface.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(surface.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(vectors.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(vectors.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(histcounts.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(histcounts.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(backend_interface.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>matplot.lib(backend_interface.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>nodesoup.lib(nodesoup.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>nodesoup.lib(nodesoup.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>nodesoup.lib(fruchterman_reingold.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>nodesoup.lib(fruchterman_reingold.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>nodesoup.lib(kamada_kawai.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>nodesoup.lib(kamada_kawai.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>nodesoup.lib(layout.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>nodesoup.lib(layout.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>nodesoup.lib(algebra.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '0' doesn't match value '2' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>nodesoup.lib(algebra.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in AutocorrelationPlot.obj
1>   Creating library C:\git\RouseModelCpp\x64\Debug\RouseModelPlot.lib and object C:\git\RouseModelCpp\x64\Debug\RouseModelPlot.exp
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>nodesoup.lib(kamada_kawai.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(vectors.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(histcounts.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>nodesoup.lib(nodesoup.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>nodesoup.lib(fruchterman_reingold.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(parallel_lines.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(stair.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(string_function.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(surface.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(filled_area.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(labels.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(matrix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(network.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(bars.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(box_chart.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(circles.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(contours.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(contourc.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(world_map_10m.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(world_map_50m.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(world_map_110m.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(line_spec.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(legend.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(error_bar.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(function_line.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(axis_type.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(line.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(histogram.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(axes_object.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(figure_registry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(colors.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(gnuplot.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(backend_registry.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(figure_type.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(axes_type.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(axes_functions.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4
1>matplot.lib(string_function.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(surface.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(vectors.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>nodesoup.lib(kamada_kawai.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(matrix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(network.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(parallel_lines.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(stair.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(circles.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(contours.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(filled_area.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(labels.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(error_bar.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(function_line.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(bars.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(box_chart.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(histogram.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(axes_object.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(line_spec.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(legend.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(colors.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(gnuplot.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(axis_type.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(line.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(figure_type.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(axes_type.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(axes_functions.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __GSHandlerCheck_EH4
1>matplot.lib(gnuplot.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_system_error_allocate_message referenced in function "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::_System_error_category::message(int)const " (?message@_System_error_category@std@@UEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@H@Z)
1>matplot.lib(gnuplot.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_system_error_deallocate_message referenced in function "public: __cdecl std::_System_error_message::~_System_error_message(void)" (??1_System_error_message@std@@QEAA@XZ)
1>matplot.lib(gnuplot.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __std_fs_convert_wide_to_narrow_replace_chars referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl std::filesystem::_Convert_wide_to_narrow_replace_chars<struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(enum __std_code_page,class std::basic_string_view<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> >,class std::allocator<char> const &)" (??$_Convert_wide_to_narrow_replace_chars@U?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@filesystem@std@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@1@W4__std_code_page@@V?$basic_string_view@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@1@AEBV?$allocator@D@1@@Z)
1>C:\git\RouseModelCpp\external_libs\lapackpp-1.9.3-win32-devel\lib\liblapackpp32.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
1>C:\git\RouseModelCpp\x64\Debug\RouseModelPlot.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "RouseModelPlotting.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You can't safely mix debug and release without isolation. If you only have a release library you can't use the debug configuration of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given Matplot++ libraries were release versions. I.e., there was no debug information available.

So, I had to download the original source code and compile it using the following commands:

```
1. git clone https://github.com/alandefreitas/matplotplusplus.git

2. cd matplotplusplus

3. mkdir build

4. cd build

5. cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..

6. cmake --build . --config Debug
```